# Error: package or namespace failed for 'ecospat'

Tags: r

I have seen similar questions for other packages and I have tried solutions offered in other posts, such as removing the package and installing it again, clearing global environment etc, but I still get the same error.

```
 > library(ecospat)
   Loading required package: ade4
   Loading required package: ape
   Loading required package: sp
   Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck =     vI[[i]]) : 
   there is no package called ‘slam’
```

I have tried updating all packages in RStudio, to no avail. I am currently trying to run a Boosted Regression Tree for data I have. If I proceed with the above error, I end up getting:

```
 Error: could not find function "ecospat.boyce"
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you don't have the `slam` package installed. Have you tried installing it first with `install.packages("slam")`, and then retry `library(ecospat)`?

Comment: I tried doing that, but RStudio gives me an error saying, no such package called slam.

Comment: Strange. `slam` exists (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/slam/index.html) Maybe try manual download and install from that link? Aside, note that `slam` isn't a direct dependency/import of `ecospat` (https://github.com/cran/ecospat/blob/master/DESCRIPTION). So this must be related to another package that `ecospat` depends on.

Comment: What version of R are you using?  Slam requires 3.3.1

Comment: Hey All, I removed ecospat and re-installed it with                                                 >install.packages("ecospat" , dependencies=T) ; that seems to work now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having the same error message but in my case, it was the package called `latticeExtra` the one missing on my computer. I tried installing that package but was not available from CRAN. Then, I looked for the tar.gz file and tried installing the package, an error message popped up saying I needed a most recent version of R. Finally, I updated my R version (from 3.5.3 to 3.6.3) and tried using the `ecospat` package, it worked!